# JBOSS AS 7 custom class loader not working

Tags: jboss, osgi, jboss7.x, classloader

We recently moved to JBOSS AS 7.Since it is based on OSGi and all modules are isolated, we are having a problem.

One of our jars is loaded by a URLclassloader from a specified directory outside of the JBOSS modules.

```
Class[] parameters = new Class[]{URL.class};
URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",parameters);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(sysloader,new Object[]{ flist[i].toURI().toURL()});
```

flist[i] contains the jar with complete path to be loaded.

Where as this used to work previously, after AS 7, this class is not getting loaded.

I know you can add these jars to the modules folder and specify dependency. But we want this to work.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: FWIW JBoss AS 7 is not based on OSGi. It uses JBoss Modules for isolation, but it's not OSGi. It does have OSGi support however.

Comment: Even then I am having an issue because of this modularization.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this? Or what should have been the right approach?

Comment: I up voted it since I share the same problem. @NeilBartlett why is this a bad idea? We have a framework web app that supports addition of new functionality via module jars. We were loading the new modules from external directory without redeploying the web app using URLClassLoader. Now with AS7 I can not do it. Any thing that worked seamlessly for a year or two is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, JBoss AS 7 is not based on OSGi, it uses its own module system ([JBoss Modules](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home)). What you're doing (reflection on classloaders) is against any rules, totally unsupported and worked only by accident. You you should is the following:

- [create](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/#_creating_a_module) a JBoss module for your JAR (the link is for a database module but should work with any JAR)
- use [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) to reference that module